# How to convert a dataframe to csv in spark

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark

How to convert a dataframe to csv in spark which is read as

```
dataFrame = spark.read.csv("testData2.csv",header='true')
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not mentioned the Spark Version. Following are the options

**Spark 1.4+**

```
dataFrame.write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').save('testdata.csv')
```

**Spark 2.0+**

```
dataFrame.write.csv('testdata.csv')
```